# Map canvas and Layout map not aligned

Tags: qgis

I have a couple of projects started where my map canvas looks as expected - all of my layers are in the same coordinate system, I'm using Google imagery from the QuickMapServices plugin - however, when I add a map to a layout, the vector linework and the aerial imagery are no longer aligned.

Image 1 is a screenshot from my map canvas, Image 2 is a screenshot when I add a map to a layout page.

What could be causing this shift between the canvas and the layout?

Image 1

[image: Image 1]

Image 2

[image: Image 2]

Comment: To be sure, does each layer really have exactly the same CRS? What is the target CRS in map layout? What is the CRS in the project? Sorry to ask nearly dumb questions but need to go back to the basics to sort out the issue.

Comment: Yes, each layer is on the same CRS - and the map layout is targeting the project CRS.  I have found what is causing the problem, but I still don't have a fix.   I have a contour layer extracted from a raster and when I apply a mask to my contour labels, that's what sets off the alignment of the layers in the layout.  If I turn the masks off, everything looks as expected.

Comment: You may open an issue if you are able to provide a reproducible sample to devs https://github.com/qgis/qgis/issues Be aware that you seem to hit the same issue as https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/44426 (need to be confirmed)